# Debian postrm running twice and failing

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

## The package:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(sim-runtime)
install(PROGRAMS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/sim-runtime-info DESTINATION bin)
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME sim-runtime)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "1.5")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "geographiclib-tools")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/postinst;${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/postrm")
include(CPack)
```

postinst:

```
#! /bin/sh
/usr/sbin/geographiclib-get-gravity wgs84
```

postrm:

```
#! /bin/sh
rm /usr/share/GeographicLib/gravity/wgs84.egm
```

`/usr/sbin/geographiclib-get-gravity` is a script provided by the `geographiclib-tools` dependency.  When I call it in postinst, it downloads `/usr/share/GeographicLib/gravity/wgs84.egm`

Because this creates an orphaned file, it makes sense to delete it when we un-install my package.  That's why I've added the `rm` command in `postrm`.

## The problem:

`dpkg -i sim-runtime-1.5-Linux.deb` works fine.  `postinst` downloads the databases appropriately and installs all files.    Then:

```
stew@stewbian:~$ sudo dpkg -P sim-runtime
(Reading database ... 228685 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing sim-runtime (1.5) ...
Purging configuration files for sim-runtime (1.5) ...
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/GeographicLib/gravity/wgs84.egm': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package sim-runtime (--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sim-runtime
```

After running this command, all files installed by the package are gone, the databases that we downloaded in `postinst` are gone.  Everything looks great, but the package itself was not marked as removed.

## Some investigation:

- My first thought is that perhaps something else automatically deleted those files before `postrm` was called.  I tried removing `postrm`.  The package uninstalls properly, but that database is left orphaned.

## The question:

How can a remove a file that was generated by `postinst`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1006945/130536).

The solution was to change `postrm` to this:

```
#! /bin/sh
if [ $1 = 'purge' ]
then
  rm /usr/share/GeographicLib/gravity/wgs84.egm
fi
```